# URI Comparer Ignoring Query String Order

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, uri, query-string

Comparing two URIs can be done with [System.Uri.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.compare(v=vs.110).aspx).
However, comparing `http://example.com/pages?pageStart=100&pageSize=50` with `http://example.com/pages?pageSize=50&pageStart=100` says the two URIs are different.  Is there any way to make the comparison ignore the order in which values appear within the querystring; as functionally the two URIs are identical.

I'm thinking of writing a wrapper method to put the query-string parameters in order before calling the standard compare function, but wanted to check first whether there was an out of the box solution, as it seems odd that the comparison wouldn't already have an option for this.

---

**Update**

This is the solution I've come up with for comparing two URIs, regardless or their querystring parameter order.  As mentioned above, this does it by first sorting the querystring of each URI.  However, if there's an existing solution within .net I'd rather drop my code & use that.

```powershell
function CompareUri ($GivenUri, $ShouldBeUri) {
    $uriComponentsOptions = ([UriComponents]::AbsoluteUri)
    $uriFormatOptions = ([UriFormat]::SafeUnescaped)
    $stringComparisonOptions = ([StringComparison]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    $a = OrderUriQueryString($GivenUri)
    $b = OrderUriQueryString($ShouldBeUri)
    [Uri]::Compare($a, $b, $uriComponentsOptions, $uriFormatOptions, $stringComparisonOptions)
}

function OrderUriQueryString($Uri) {
    [System.UriBuilder]$UriBuilder = New-Object -TypeName 'System.UriBuilder' -ArgumentList $Uri
    [System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection]$Query = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($UriBuilder.Query)
    [System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection]$Query2 = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString('') #we have to initialise this way as HttpValueCollection has no public constructor (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/HttpValueCollection.cs,fde6b9ec5f1ed58a,references)  
    $Query.AllKeys | sort | %{ $Query2.Add($_, $Query[$_]) }
    $UriBuilder.Query = $Query2.ToString()
    $UriBuilder.ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is basically the same thing you did but if you really just wanted the compare to look a little more succinct in code, you can modify the `System.Uri` type with `Update-TypeData` and use that instead of two individual functions. It's not native .NET and basically uses the same code you have, but at least the call for comparison looks a little cleaner.

```
Update-TypeData -MemberType "ScriptMethod" -MemberName "SortedQueryStringCompare" -TypeName "System.Uri" -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" -Value {
    Param (
        [System.URI]$ComparingURI
    )

    $Sorter = {
        $UriBuilder = [System.UriBuilder]$args[0]

        $UnsortedQuery = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($UriBuilder.Query)
        $SortedQuery = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString([String]::Empty)
        $UnsortedQuery.AllKeys | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object { 
            $SortedQuery.Add($_, $UnsortedQuery[$_])
        }

        $UriBuilder.Query = $SortedQuery.ToString()
        return $UriBuilder.ToString()
    }

    $UriComponentsOptions = ([UriComponents]::AbsoluteUri)
    $UriFormatOptions = ([UriFormat]::SafeUnescaped)
    $StringComparisonOptions = ([StringComparison]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    $OriginUriString = . $Sorter $This
    $ComparingUriString = . $Sorter $ComparingURI

    return [System.Uri]::Compare($OriginUriString,
                                 $ComparingUriString,
                                 $UriComponentsOptions,
                                 $UriFormatOptions,
                                 $StringComparisonOptions)
}

$e1 = [System.Uri]"http://example.com/pages?pageStart=100&pageSize=50"
$e2 = [System.Uri]"http://example.com/pages?pageSize=50&pageStart=100"

$e1.SortedQueryStringCompare($e2)
```

---

Or just do this with a `SortQueryString` method instead and use that for a call to `Compare`

```
Update-TypeData -MemberType "ScriptMethod" -MemberName "SortQueryString" -TypeName "System.Uri" -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" -Value {
    $UriBuilder = [System.UriBuilder]$this

    $UnsortedQuery = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($UriBuilder.Query)
    $SortedQuery = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString([String]::Empty)
    $UnsortedQuery.AllKeys | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object { 
        $SortedQuery.Add($_, $UnsortedQuery[$_])
    }

    $UriBuilder.Query = $SortedQuery.ToString()
    return [System.Uri]$UriBuilder.ToString()
}

$UriComponentsOptions = ([UriComponents]::AbsoluteUri)
$UriFormatOptions = ([UriFormat]::SafeUnescaped)
$StringComparisonOptions = ([StringComparison]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)

$e1 = [System.Uri]"http://example.com/pages?pageStart=100&pageSize=50"
$e2 = [System.Uri]"http://example.com/pages?pageSize=50&pageStart=100"

[System.Uri]::Compare($e1.SortQueryString(), 
                      $e2.SortQueryString(), 
                      $UriComponentsOptions, 
                      $UriFormatOptions, 
                      $StringComparisonOptions)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `Update-TypeData`; I'd not come across that one before; great trick.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an ordered hash table of query parameters

```
$queryURI = http://example.com/pages?

$Parameters = [ordered] @{
            startsize = $startsize
            pagesize = $pagesize

        }
```

Then build the query with the given parameters

```
foreach ($item in $Parameters.GetEnumerator())
        {

            if ($item.value -ne $null)
            {

                $query = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($uriBuilder.Query)
                $query[$item.key] = $item.Value

                $uriBuilder = [System.UriBuilder]::new($queryURI)
                $uriBuilder.Query = $query.ToString()
                $queryURI = $uriBuilder.ToString()
            }



        }
```

here is a complete example

```
$QueryURI = 'http://example.com/pages?'


Function Get-MyQueryURL
{
    #takes 2 params 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                   ValueFromPipeline = $true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [String[]]$startsize,
        [String[]]$pagesize



    ) #end param 

    Begin { }
    process
    {

        $Parameters = [ordered] @{
            startsize = $startsize
            pagesize = $pagesize
        }




        foreach ($item in $Parameters.GetEnumerator())
        {

            if ($item.value -ne $null)
            {

                $query = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($uriBuilder.Query)
                $query[$item.key] = $item.Value

                $uriBuilder = [System.UriBuilder]::new($QueryURI)
                $uriBuilder.Query = $query.ToString()
                $QueryURI = $uriBuilder.ToString()
            }



        }
            Write-Host $QueryURI
    }
}
```

with the following result: the query strings are ordered

```
PS C:\Scripts> Get-MyQueryURL -startsize 100 -pagesize 50
http://example.com:80/pages?startsize=100&pagesize=50

PS C:\Scripts> Get-MyQueryURL -pagesize 50 -startsize 100
http://example.com:80/pages?startsize=100&pagesize=50
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Sadly `[ordered]` retains the input order, rather than sorting the keys into order itself, so I still have the problem of having to manually sort the keys in the same way I did with the NameValueCollection / still have the problem that `URI.Compare` requires this sorting to take place.

Comment: i think you can input the query strings in any order, but they will always become ordered - that is it should negate the original problem for a set of identical query strings

Comment: Agreed were I using this to construct the URIs.  However I have existing URIs which I'd like to compare with one another.

Comment: you can use -split on the query strings